# Too many clicks required to unsubscribe from "Latest jobs" email

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

In short: please make unsubscription from "Latest jobs" easier by reducing the required steps.

Full details and own suggestion:

[Careers site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) allows a user to subscribe to job listing based on some factors. All good. This results in a daily email with jobs matching what the user selected. Still good.

However, suppose I want to unsubscribe. I expected a one click link "unsubscribe", but instead saw only "[Manage my subscriptions](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/subscribe)" link in the end of the email. OK, no biggie - clicked it.

Now the next screen is actually where one is *subscribing to a new list* - the current subscriptions are below the "Add Subscription" section. But hey, one step closer!

> [image]

Now clicking the "edit or unsubscribe" link brings me to the final frontier:

> [image]

And clicking "unsubscribe" finally remove the subscription. (without confirmation, but that's a different issue, outside the scope here)

Three clicks required to unsubscribe from a single subscription. Can this please be reduced to two, by changing the link in the email to something like "Edit or unsubscribe", linking to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/subscribe?id=[id here]`? This will also reduce the time spent on skimming through existing subscriptions, looking for the one you want to unsubscribe from.

Comment: It should be noted that in many European jurisdictions, due to EU guidelines, this procedure will be considered overly complex. So there's also legal issues involved here potentially.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes well, I believe those rules are about "forced subscriptions" e.g. getting advertisements when buying a product and forgetting to untick "send me advertisements". In this case, the subscription process is very clear, so I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We send one e-mail for all job searches that you're subscribed to. In this case the 'Manage my subscriptions' link is intended for you to be able to remove either individual subscriptions from the email **or** everything (in which case you stop receiving the email).

We could add an individual unsubscribe link to each subscription, I'll add it to the backlog.

**UPDATE**
I've added a 'Manage' link to each subscription in the email which links to the search details for the subscription. From there you can edit the criteria used for it or unsubscribe. It still needs to be localized but is there in English for now.

[image: Individual Subscription Management]

Comment: Awesome, saw the edit just now. ( no notification for edits :( )